# How to take a directory or file backup using command?

Tags: command-line, directory, backup

I have uploaded my file there will be a daily changes in that file for safer side i want to take backup that directory,when i tried copy that folder to another it is showing whenever i have created date only i need to take latest backup of my directory,any suggestions to get latest backup of my file

Comment: you need to explain better the situation and what you need. It seems you have a directory where backups of something are created, the creation date is in the filename? You want each time to take the latest backup and copy it (`cp`) to an other folder keeping many of them, or you want to `rsync` latest backup with your destination folder? be more verbose

Comment: @ lese - thanks for your response ..one of my directory is there i want to take backup that directory and i want save it in another folder ..becoz i am using customer system i can use cmd prompt only..when i am copying the same folder into another it is not showing updated whenever i have created that date only showing by the copied folder.

Comment: @ lese - in that directory i have sub directories and files also.

Comment: Show us what commands you typed and what output you have.  Show us example file and directory listings and example times and dates.  Your description is not enough.  There are too many variables to assume.

Comment: @ lese-  cp -avr var/www/trans /home/transgenic i need back up of trans file in my transgenic.

Comment: @ lese - and that copied file details is showing whenever i created that directory that date is showing for both

Answer (score 1):

If your file is text, you could use `git` for backup and revision history.

e.g.

```
cd /path/to/uploaded/file
git init
git add myfile.txt
git commit -m $(date +%Y%m%d) myfile.txt
```

and then, whenever there's a new version you run

```
git commit -m $(date +%Y%m%d) myfile.txt
```

Now that it's in `git` you can see differences between any two versions, restore any previous version, etc.  `git` is space-efficient, too - it only stores the differences between versions of a file for any update.

You can also set it up so that the master git repository is in another directory or on another machine...and you can update the master by running `git push` after running `git commit`.

There's a **lot** more to `git` but those are the basic commands, all you really need for simple usage.

`git` has a **lot** of built-in help.  e.g. run `git help everyday` for a mini-tutorial on 20 everyday git commands.

Comment: @ Cas - it  is not file it is directory.

Comment: btw, it does work for binary files too (e.g. pics and pdfs etc).  but it's more commonly used for text files - program source code, config files, etc.